# option tag with multiple word value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have problem with sending multiple word values with post. for example if I send string "Jazz and Blues" it send only "Jazz". Do you know where is problem?? Thanks for help.

```
<select name="zaner" required>

    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
    $z = array("Elektro", "Drum and Bass", "Hardcore", "House", "Techno", "Trance", "Dubstep", "Folk", "Pop", "Jazz and Blues", "Reggae", "RnB", "Rap", "Metal", "Punk", "Clasic", "Alternative", "Indie", "Rock", "Country", "Disco", "Funky", "Experimental", "Soul and ghospe");
    foreach ($z as $zaner) {                        
        echo "<option value=" .$zaner. ">" .$zaner. "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: `<select name="zaner[]" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: Also, change `"<option value=" .$zaner. ">" .$zaner. "</option>";` to `"<option value='$zaner'>$zaner</option>";`.

Comment: "<option value='$zaner'>$zaner</option>";  This helped!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As N.B. mentioned, you forgot to specify `multiple="multiple"` in your select tag, i.e.

```
<select name="zaner[]" multiple="multiple" required>
    <option value=""></option>
<?php
$z = array("Elektro", "Drum and Bass", "Hardcore", "House", "Techno", "Trance", "Dubstep", "Folk", "Pop", "Jazz and Blues", "Reggae", "RnB", "Rap", "Metal", "Punk", "Clasic", "Alternative", "Indie", "Rock", "Country", "Disco", "Funky", "Experimental", "Soul and ghospe");
foreach ($z as $zaner) {                        
    echo "<option value=" .$zaner. ">" .$zaner. "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: well I dont want to send multiple selections like "House" + "Dubstep", but I want to send only one like "Drum and Bass". But my problem is that it doesnt send whole string "Drum and Bass" but it send only "Drum"